# Elementary Oracle SQL Error message ORA-00900

Tags: sql, oracle

I'm fairly new to writing SQL but I have a decent understanding of the basics at this point. I am trying to figure out why I am receiving the following error message: ORA-00900: invalid SQL statement.

Additionally, it would help if I could find which line is causing the error.

```
CREATE TABLE ADVENTURE_TRIP (
    COLUMN CHAR(15) PRIMARY KEY,
    TYPE CHAR(15),
    LENGTH CHAR(15),
    DECIMAL_PLACES CHAR(15),
    NULLS_ALLOWED CHAR(15) NOT NULL, 
    DESCRIPTION CHAR(25)
);
```

Comment: Please do not use the `char` data type. It has absolutely no advantage over `varchar2` but many disadvantages. And columns named `decimal_places` or `length` should probably be defined as `number`  -  **never** store numbers (or dates) in a char or varchar column.

Comment: you could use `trip_type`, `duration`/`adventure_duration`/`trip_duration` for column names.

Answer (score 3):

The word `COLUMN` is a reserved word, and is not appropriate for a column name.  You should choose a better name for the column.

Although `TYPE` is also a reserved word, it is allowed as a column name.  I would change that too.

Also, usually `VARCHAR2()` is preferred over `CHAR()` for string types in Oracle.

The list of reserved words is [here](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/em.102/b40103/app_oracle_reserved_words.htm).

Comment: Thank you! Looks like column was the issue. Will use Varchar2 in the future. That's very helpful!

Answer (score 0):

@Gordon described the correct justification.
Reserved keywords should be avoided.

But, If you really want to create the table as mentioned in your question then you can use the following code:

```
CREATE TABLE ADVENTURE_TRIP (
    "COLUMN" CHAR(15) PRIMARY KEY,
    "TYPE" CHAR(15),
    LENGTH CHAR(15),
    DECIMAL_PLACES CHAR(15),
    NULLS_ALLOWED CHAR(15) NOT NULL, 
    DESCRIPTION CHAR(25)
);
```

Double quotes can be used for such purpose.
This is just to make you understand but in the real world, you must avoid using reserved keywords.
Here is the [Demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=64f881ea0b405e4dbabdac6270617a6e)